# Ordenamiento de un vector numérico en el gráfico generado por ggplot al usar facet_wrap

Tags: r

Tengo un código como el que sigue:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Calculo unas cuantas medias cualquiera
mean_data <- group_by(df, Duration, Time.elapsed,P_R_coef, R_L_coef) %>%
  summarise(mean_A = mean(Number.of.theories.to.be.discovered, na.rm = TRUE), mean_B = mean(Number.of.published.theories.CK, na.rm = TRUE), mean_C = mean(Number.of.refuted.theories, na.rm = TRUE), mean_D = mean(Number.of.true.published.theories, na.rm = TRUE), mean_E = mean(Number.of.false.published.theories, na.rm = TRUE), mean_F = mean(Theta, na.rm = TRUE))

#Hago un gráfico cualquiera
ggplot(mean_data %>% mutate(group = paste(as.numeric(P_R_coef),as.numeric(P_R_coef),Duration, sep="-")),
  aes(Time.elapsed)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_A, colour = "Nb.T.to.be.discovered")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_B, colour = "Nb.T.published.CK")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_C, colour = "Nb.T.refuted")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_D, colour = "Nb.true.published")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_E, colour = "Nb.false.published")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_F*200, colour = "Theta")) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free", labeller = label_both)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Mean", color = "Epistemic landscape") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    "Mean", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./200, name = "Theta")
  )
```

Al hacer el gráfico el ordenamiento de la gráfica que obtengo es incorrecto. Como se observa en la última fila del gráfico, facet_wrap muestra antes P_R_coef 10 que P_R_coef 2.

He intentado hacer mil cosas pero no consiguo reordenar los valores numéricos en la gráfica. Mi objetivo es que en la última fila del gráfico, 2 y 3 aparezcan antes que 10.

Si hay alguna sugerencia viendo el código lo agradezco. Si no es algo obvio, podría subir alguna estructura de datos mínima.

[Muestra de datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt8o5gjs7lxihs0/muestra.csv?dl=0)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es crear la variable grupo antes del grafico en  mean_data de la misma forma que la estas creando. Luego imprimir sus valores únicos y ordenarlos manualmente en un nuevo vector. Por ultimo transformar la variable grupo a tipo factor y asignarle los niveles ordenados manualmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el orden no es numérico sino lexicográfico y `2-1-180` siempre va a estar luego de `10-1-160`. Se me ocurren dos alternativas.

#### 1. Hacer un "zero-fill" de las cadenas:

```
library(stringr)

mutate(group = paste(str_pad(P_R_coef, 2, "0"),
                     str_pad(R_L_coef, 2, "0"), 
                     str_pad(Duration, 2, "0"), sep="-"))
```

Nota: estoy asumiendo que el segundo valor es `R_L_coef` aunque en tu ejemplo sigue siendo `P_R_coef`

#### 2. Convertir la variable en un `factor` y reordenarla a gusto

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group = factor(paste(as.numeric(P_R_coef),
                              as.numeric(R_L_coef),
                              Duration, sep="-")),
         group = factor(group, 
                        levels=unique(group[order(P_R_coef,R_L_coef,Duration)]), 
                        ordered=TRUE)
         ) -> df
```

Usando el criterio 2 y re interpretando tu "batch", entiendo que podrías resolverlo de esta manera:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Duration, Time.elapsed, P_R_coef, R_L_coef) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Number.of.theories.to.be.discovered,
                    Number.of.published.theories.CK,
                    Number.of.refuted.theories,
                    Number.of.true.published.theories,
                    Number.of.false.published.theories,
                    Theta),
               mean,
               na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Number.of.theories.to.be.discovered:Theta) %>% 
  mutate(group = paste(round(P_R_coef,2),
                       round(R_L_coef,2),
                       Duration,
                       sep="-"),
         group = factor(group, 
                        levels=unique(group[order(P_R_coef,R_L_coef,Duration)]), 
                        ordered=TRUE)
  ) -> plot_data

plot_data %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Time.elapsed, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free", labeller = label_both)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Mean", color = "Epistemic landscape") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    "Mean", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./200, name = "Theta")
  )
```

Revisa `plot_data` que serían los datos finales a graficar. La lǵica de `grupo` pasa por convertir a un factor reordenarlo por las columnas que componen la etiqueta del factor. Luego opte por el uso del `sumarize_at()` para mantener los nombres de columna y el `pivot_longer()` para evitar tener que definir múltiples `geom_lines()`.

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho, como siempre. Me salen dos errores. En elprimer caso: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `group`.
i `group = paste(...)`.
x 'arg' should be one of “left”, “right”, “both”
i The error occurred in group 1: Duration = 60, Time.elapsed = 0, P_R_coef = 0.4444444.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. |||||||||||| En el segundo: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `group`.
i `group = factor(...)`.
x `group` must return compatible vectors across groups |||| Si no, puedo compartir algún dato.

Comment: Si, deberías compartir una muestra de los datos, yo antes de responderte lo probé con datos generados sinteticamente y obviamente funcionó bien.

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho. Disculpa la demora. He dejado una pequeña muestra de datos enlazados en la pregunta.

Comment: Hola @Patricio Moracho, ¿le echaste un vistazo al error?

Comment: Si, lo revisé pero se me complica un poco la lógica que has usado, voy a agregarte una edición con lo que pude interpretar.